# Multiple Contributors on fortrabbit

Tags: php, git, fortrabbit

I want to know, if I can open an account and I have two contributors to my repository. Can I?
ps: I talk about GIT, only GIT permission

Comment: Why don't you ask Fortrabbit service desk for help (it's a commercial service)?

Comment: I know that it is to payment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking. Please ask tech related questions that probably help users later on here on SO. There are professional support plan with fortrabbit, but you can also just ask the customer service.

To answer your question: With fortrabbit there is no GitHub-style of pull-request workflow. You can however use all standard Git features like pull, merge, commit messages, branching etc. Within the fortrabbit Dashboard you can invite and manage users based on different access roles > code access via SSH keys. You can also combine Bitbucket or GitHub with a hosting platform such as fortrabbit.

From the fortrabbit documentation:

- [Working with Git](http://help.fortrabbit.com/git)
- [Integrating GitHub/Bitucket](http://help.fortrabbit.com/bitbucket-github-and-fortrabbit)
- [Collaboration](http://help.fortrabbit.com/collaboration)